# how to zoom in and zoom out an image on clicking button in iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimageview, uiimage

I have image in a imageview which is placed in a scrollview., Zoom in and out are performed  on pinches,

now, i want to zoom in and out on clicking buttons placed for zoom in and zoom out.

how to do it? Is there any option? if anyone knows please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can already resize the image based on pinch gestures, I can hardly imagine you would have difficulty responding to button events instead. Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: i didn't understand how to achieve that functionality, can u please guide me with an example using code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the zoom scale of the scroll view programatically based on the tap of a button. A simple implementation:

```
- (IBAction)zoomIn:(id)sender {
    if(scrollView.zoomScale < scrollView.maximumZoomScale) {
        scrollView.zoomScale = (scrollView.zoomScale + 0.1);
    }
}


- (IBAction)zoomOut:(id)sender {
    if(scrollView.zoomScale > scrollView.minimumZoomScale) {
        scrollView.zoomScale = (scrollView.zoomScale - 0.1);
    }
}
```